# Passing by Reference instead of by Value, Why?

Tags: c#, reference

What I'm trying to do is dump the names and scores of my playerlist into a temp array for sorting so that they can be displayed on the scoreboard.

For some reason it seems to be keeping the reference to the values rather than the values themselves.  After sorting the scoreboard reads "player 4 - score 4" for every entry.  I know the sorting method works, I've used it previously in another game.

The initial values are 
player1 - 1 
player2 - 2 
player3 - 3 
player4 - 4

One thing that is missing is dumping the scores into the scorelist every update.  i took it out after trying to rearrange things to make it work.

please help me understand why this is happening.  I read this article here and it didn't help much.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.71).aspx

initialize

```
  ScoresList = DumpListToArray(PlayerManager.PlayerList);
```

Update

```
SortKillScores(ScoresList);
```

Draw

```
private static void DrawKillScores(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "" + ScoresList[i].Name + " - " + ScoresList[i].KillScore, new Vector2(900, 0 + 20 * i), Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 0.5f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);  
        }

    }
```

Methods

```
private static ScoreHolder[] DumpListToArray(List<Player> tempList)
    {
        ScoreHolder[] tempArray = new ScoreHolder[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            tempArray[i] = new ScoreHolder();
            tempArray[i].Name = tempList[i].PlayerName;
            tempArray[i].KillScore = tempList[i].KillScore;
            tempArray[i].TimeScore = tempList[i].TimeScore;
            tempArray[i].PointScore = tempList[i].PointScore;
        }

        return tempArray;
    }

    private static void SortKillScores(ScoreHolder[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int k = i; k > 0 && array[k].KillScore > array[k - 1].KillScore; k--)
            {
                int score = array[k].KillScore;
                string name = array[k].Name;
                array[k] = array[k - 1];
                array[k - 1].KillScore = score;
                array[k - 1].Name = name;
            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: could you post the source for Player please?

Comment: Please show the code where you're calling `DumpListToArray` and `SortKillScores`.

Comment: Are you using `ref` or `out` somewhere?  Or are you storing an object itself in memory?  We need more information.

Comment: Why are you swapping the members of an array with `array[k] = array[k-1]` and then copying properties. Just swap the actual members!

Comment: Thank you all for your interest in helping me.  Seems Matt Burlands answer resolved the issue.  Though I still don't understand why this code had worked in a previous game fine as it was.

Comment: Check out my answer as well to maybe give you an alternative to how you are sorting the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than trying to copy properties from one cell to the other, just swap the cells:

```
private static void SortKillScores(ScoreHolder[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int k = i; k > 0 && array[k].KillScore > array[k - 1].KillScore; k--)
        {
            var temp = array[k];
            array[k] = array[k - 1];
            array[k - 1] = temp;
        }
    }       
}
```

What you had was copying a reference to the same item to `array[k]` and then editing the item in `k-1` which *is the same item*!

```
int score = array[k].KillScore;
string name = array[k].Name;
array[k] = array[k - 1];          // cells k and k-1 are the same item!
array[k - 1].KillScore = score;   // this changes both k and k-1
array[k - 1].Name = name;         // and so does this!
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!  That seems to fix it!  Though I still don't understand why it would behave this way when i used it in the past like that with no issues?

Answer (score 1):

@MattBurland seems to cover you here, but to expand, if you are only trying to sort, you should try using the [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) method.

```
private static ScoreHolder[] SortKillScores(ScoreHolder[] array)
{
    return array.OrderBy(e => e.KillScore);
}
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know it was that easy to sort an array. Changed a few things now, so in update i have ScoresList = DumpListToScoreArray(PlayerManager.PlayerList); ScoresList = ScoresList.OrderBy(e => e.KillScore).ToArray(); Question, can u control ascending/descending with this? If not i can just print my list in array in reverse, no biggy, just curious.

Comment: OrderBy(e => -e.KillScore)
or
OrderByDescending(e => e.KillScore)